# How to trigger an event after the user lose focus on a?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to visual basic. I have a TextBox, and I want to trigger an event when the user lose focus on the textBox.

I tried writing

```
Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus()

     something
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub TextBox_Leave()

     something
End Sub
```

I don't really understand how they work, I have

```
Private Sub TextBox_Change()

    something
End Sub
```

and that works fine, so what am I missing? How do I trigger the event when the user is not writing in the textbox anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

End Sub
```

There's a helper -- when you're in the code editor, you'll see two list boxes above the editor.  The list on the left contains the available objects for the current module.  Select `TextBox` from there if it isn't already selected.  The list box on the right contains the available Events.  You should see `Exit` in there.  Clicking that will paste in the code above.

Comment: thanks, I founded it by myself like a minute after you posted.